# Memory leak Error when connect redis with lettuce client

Tags: spring-boot, redis, lettuce

I am using lettuce to connect to redis: spring-boot-starter-redis :2.0.6.RELEASE, when I startup the app it come out this error:

```
[ERROR][main][ResourceLeakDetector][error] - LEAK: 
HashedWheelTimer.release() was not called before it's garbage- 
collected. See http://netty.io/wiki/reference-counted-objects.html for 
more information.
Recent access records: 
Created at:
io.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer.<init>(HashedWheelTimer.java:272)
io.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer.<init>(HashedWheelTimer.java:216)
io.lettuce.core.resource.DefaultClientResources.<init>(DefaultClientResources.java:163)
io.lettuce.core.resource.DefaultClientResources$Builder.build(DefaultClientResources.java:461)
io.lettuce.core.resource.DefaultClientResources.create(DefaultClientResources.java:229)
io.lettuce.core.AbstractRedisClient.<init>(AbstractRedisClient.java:96)
io.lettuce.core.RedisClient.<init>(RedisClient.java:86)
io.lettuce.core.RedisClient.create(RedisClient.java:123)
org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory.lambda$createClient$7(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:853)
java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267)
org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory.createClient(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:853)
org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory.afterPropertiesSet(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:232)
```

redis config file :

```
  public class RedisConfig {

  @Bean
  RedisConnectionFactory lettuceConnectionFactory(RedisProperties 
   redisProperties) {
   // 
  }

  @Bean
  public RedisTemplate<String, Object> 
  redisTemplate(LettuceConnectionFactory lettuceConnectionFactory) {

  }

  private RedisStandaloneConfiguration connection(RedisProperties 
  redisProperties) {

  }
 }
```

config yaml file :

```
  spring:      
   redis:
     host: 
     lettuce:
      pool:
       max-active:  100
```

is anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

If you use many `RedisClient` instances in your application - you need to share between them `ClientResources` object.

The typical way to create RedisClient is:

```java
    RedisClient.create("someUrl");
```

But this way of object creation is not recommended when you want create multiple instances.
Inside `RedisClient` there is field with heavy object: `ClientResources`
When you are creating many instances of `RedisClient` then error can be produced during runtime

```
LEAK: You are creating too many HashedWheelTimer instances.  HashedWheelTimer is a shared resource that must be reused across the JVM,so that only a few instances are created.
```

What you can do is to create one shared `ClientResources` in your application. And pass this object to the constructor `RedisClient`.

For example:

```java
    ClientResources sharedResources = DefaultClientResources.create();

    //and use this between many RedisClients i.e.:

    RedisClient first = RedisClient.create(sharedResources, "someUrl");
    RedisClient second = RedisClient.create(sharedResources, "someUrl_222");
    RedisClient third = RedisClient.create(sharedResources, "someUrl_3333");
```

For more deatils, please visit [HERE](https://github.com/lettuce-io/lettuce-core/wiki/Configuring-Client-resources)

Comment: It take effect,greate！

Answer (score 1):

This type of error typically occurs when multiple instances of `RedisClient` get created without sharing `ClientResources`.

Spring Boot creates a singleton instance so any other instances are likely to be created by either your code or external dependencies. Without further context, it's not possible to say more.

Comment: Hi @mp911de , I've update the post with my config files,  please take a look

Comment: If you're creating such bean from your code, I would suggest  you to create ClientResources bean before LettuceConnectionConfiguration runs  and add it to spring context and use same for your usecase,  or you can do the other way where you  just autowire the bean created by auto config and use it for beans created by you.